# Outlook New Mail Notification Icon Hides

Tags: microsoft-outlook, icons

I have Outlook minimize to tray. I set the "Microsoft Outlook" icon to "Show icon and notification" in the **Notification Area Icons** settings (this is the main Outlook "O" icon). That one works fine.

I also have the "**Microsoft Outlook (You have new unread email messages.)**" icon set to "**Show icon and notification**" (this is the envelope icon). That one works for a while, but then it gets hidden. When I go back into the **Notification Area Icons settings**, it still shows up as "Show icon and notification" but there is another one in the list that has the same envelope icon and shows some weird file name, currently it's `339e3812.rbf (You have new unread email messages.)` and it is set to "**Only show notifications**".

If I change it to "**Show icon and notification**" it comes back, but then after a while it will change to a different file name and disappear again. Why does it do this? Is there any way to make the envelope icon always appear when there is new mail?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you check "Always show all icons and notifications in the taskbar"? Does it eventually hide again?

Comment: If I check that it shows the entire stack of icons, including the one I want. But that takes up waaaay too much screen real estate. I don't want all of them shown, just a couple.

Comment: I wasn't trying to solve your problem, merely diagnose it. So it does not go away eventually? Also, what version of Outlook are you working in?

Comment: As you can see here http://imgur.com/ifSlj53 my outlook "new mail" notification icon is properly named, unlike yours. I do not know the specific fix, but it's something with that weird .rbf file. EDIT: I'm using 2010.

Comment: Ah I see. It does not go away if I have that checked. I'm using 2013.

Comment: Mine is properly named for a while, then it changes.

Comment: My only suggestion right now is to disable the notifications, both in the tray and in Outlook, do a CLEAN boot of Outlook, then change the settings back and restart Outlook.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have no unread messages in your mail.  Send yourself an email. The icon should appear. BEFORE it disappears right click your taskbar > Properties and "Customize.." and you will see a new Icon there that is not in the list if you try this without having the unread mail icon showing.

It is called Microsoft Outlook and underneath says You have new unread e-mail messages.  Change the behavior of this from "only show notifications" to "show icon and notifications"

Now it should stay.  What a horrible way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 Outlook 2016.

I found that when you have a new unread email, and the envelope icon is visible, click on the up arrow to reveal all of the others. The new mail icon will join that group. Drag it into the lower notification area and then it should stay there.